# How can I find the largest table cell height with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with cells of variable-length text-content.  I want to find the height of the tallest cell and then make all the cells that height.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like this:

```
var max = 0;    
$('table td').each(function() {
    max = Math.max($(this).height(), max);
}).height(max);
```

In plain english, loop through all the cells and find the maximum value, then apply that value to all the cells.

Comment: +1 because it's short, but you can optimize it. You can remove `max===false ||` for example. And I think you should move `$(this).height()` into a variable, which saves you a couple of double function calls

Comment: Wait, you already fixed it. That's a really good solution I think

Comment: @Harmen, thanks, now uses `Math.max()` which simplifies it quite a bit.

Comment: Nice solution, I like the use of chaining too.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be different:

```
var heights = $('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get();

var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);

$('td').css('height', maxHeight);
```

Comment: Do you really need to save the height of all table cells in an array? This would mean you actually have to scan over them three times. The first time to get all heights, a second iteration to get the maximum height and the third time to set the maximum height.

Comment: Garbage collecting takes care off the array at the end.  You don't think comparing each and every height takes some CPU power?  Math.max.apply() is extremely efficient.  Sorry I posted something different from the norm.  If you benchmark it, it wins.  I prefer Tatu's example personally, people understand chaining.

Comment: You may be right there, I can't undo my downvote anymore, next time I'll just add a comment before I press the down vote button

Comment: The presence of civility always makes me appreciate the great service that is SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+max+height) that can do this for you. However, the code would look like this:

```
var tallest = 0;
$('table td').each(function() {
  if (tallest < $(this).height()) {
    tallest = $(this).height();
  }
});

$('table td').css({'height': tallest});
```

Answer (score 0):

contribute @tatu ulmanen's example

This is obvious but if you just want to strech the rows with taller cells wrap a tr loop :)

```
$('table tr').each(function (){
    var max = 0;
    $(this).find('td').each(function (){
        max = Math.max($(this).height(), max);
    }).height(max);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery with the following code

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('#yourTableID td').each(function(index, value)
{
if ($(value).height() > maxHeight)
maxHeight = $(value.height());
}).each(function(index, value) {
$(value).height() = maxHeight;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wait, what's going on here: `$(value).height() = maxHeight`. The setter requires `maxHeight` as a function argument, while no arguments will return the height. And why wouldn't you use `this` after all?